# HTML <strong> tag

Tags: html, tags

Is using more than one

```
<strong>
```

tag actually make the word stronger?

i.e. is

```
<strong><strong>abc</strong></strong>
```

stronger than

```
<strong>abc</strong>
```

?

I'm asking this because if you view the HTML source of the official website of North Korea,
http://www.korea-dpr.com/  you will see it has many strong tags. Is this supposed to be something like an IE hack?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They hope to prove North Korea has the strongest links in the world.

Comment: what the? theres over 9000 (actually 900) strong elements in that page.

Comment: Wow, just viewed that source and just... wow. They are probably trying to game search engines. I doubt that approach does what they want it to. Or maybe they are trying to make screen readers yell really loudly at people.

Comment: That was posted on The Daily WTF yesterday http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Strong-Web-Design.aspx

Comment: Although official governmental websites in general are very professional, of course this might be the exception...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[image]

Yes, you can nest strong tags and the more you nest, the stronger it becomes. Although I'd say beyond 2-3 nested is extraneous.

> The relative level of importance of a
>   piece of content is given by its
>   number of ancestor strong elements;
>   each strong element increases the
>   importance of its contents.

Source: [HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element)

Some modern user agents will apply `font-weight:bolder;` to `strong`, though since it's already **bold** you won't really notice a visual difference. If you want, you can apply a rule such as the % so nested strong elements become larger, as indicated in the other answer.

<del>Some screen readers might dictate the word out more loudly.</del>

Seems like JAWS/Window Eyes screen readers don't indicate importance, according to [this](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/?p=41).

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I believe you, but I'm curious about the specifics.

Comment: @Gert G - Actually I was wrong. I updated with a link to tests.

Comment: Wow, imagine a screen reader that dictates words incrementally loudly trying to read that site. Ears will bleed.

Comment: Never mind my last comment. Sometimes I just need to read things twice. Edit: Oh, but you just did. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, I think it could be made to do this with a relative CSS declaration like such:

```
strong { font-size: 120%; }
```

Comment: `font-size` will only increase the size of the text, not the weight.  I think what he needs is `font-weight`.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

`<strong>` is a semantic tag, as all HTML tags. It don't say that that word is bold, but that have a strong emphasis. You have to use CSS to style the element.I suggest you to read this  [CSS Property: font-weight](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/font-weight/) and the whole website.
Anyway usually web fonts don't have more than one level of "boldness" so you have to denote emphasis in another way (font size, color, etc...)

Comment: According to CSS1 standards they do have more than 1 level of boldness, hence the "bolder" and "lighter" values for the font-weight property. You are right however that it doesn't look much different in most browsers, so practical use of that is questionable.

Comment: He's talking about the fonts themselves. I.e. you will have *Verdana Medium* and *Verdana Bold* but not also *Verdana Book,* *Verdana Extra Light,* etc.

Answer (score 1):

Like other have said, use a percentage if you want each nested one to make it even larger.  If you want (I don't know why you would) to control explicitly how many deep you can go and what other attributes that entails, then you could also say

```
strong { font-weight: 100; }
strong strong { font-weight: 300; font-size: 1.1em }
strong strong strong { font-weight: 500; font-size: 1.1em; color: red; }
```

edit: by percentage, i meant to use font-weight: bolder... not percentage font-weights (which I'm not sure are supported)

Comment: I believe that font-weight:normal; = font-weight:400; so it should start there :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I don't think nesting `<strong>` tags will make it stronger.</strike>

**Edit** Guess I was wrong about nesting bold tags make the font stronger based on other answers.

I would recommend using CSS with class names instead of `<strong>`. The CSS `font-weight` property offers a variety of options that you can use to incrementally bold a word

```
.strong
{
    font-weight: bold; 
    /* Other options bold, bolder, lighter, normal, 100...900 */
}

.stronger
{
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.strongest
{
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: There's no point really in making it a class.  You should be using a CSS reset anyway, so why make a new class for something that's already built-in?  In addition, I think class selector are the most inefficient in CSS rendering speed, so using the built-in <strong> tag would also be faster (though I'm not sure there would be a noticeable difference)

Comment: @Bradley Herman, its just an example.  In the real work it would probably be combined with other CSS properties to give the desired full outcome.  You can also make multiple classes such as `.strong`, `.stronger` and `.strongest`.

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but the reason was probably that your original post was a CSS alternative to simpler CSS. No need for a class name if you're styling the tag. Your edit does make sense since it's now a preferable solution to nesting multiple strong tags.

Comment: In my original example there was just a `.strong` class. But it was a class so it could be applied to any element not just `<strong>` tags.